# Can the Jena OntModel SubModel(Model) API pass in an OntModel?

Tags: java, model, jena

I'm using the Jena OntModel api and I had a question regarding

```
    addSubModel(Model model)
```

I was wondering if I could instead use

```
    addSubModel(OntModel ontModel)
```

Would this would cause any issues?

Also, if I were to do

```
    OntModel ontModel ...; //Create a proper OntModel
    model.addSubModel(ontModel);
```

Would this be treated as a reference where if I change ontModel it'll change model and vice-versa?

I.E. If I changed ontModel (After executing the above code) from

```
   <rdf:RDF
       xmlns:rdf=1
   </rdf:RDF>
```

to

```
   <rdf:RDF
       xmlns:rdf=2
   </rdf:RDF>
```

would model reflect these changes?

Comment: What are those two examples at the end? Neither is valid RDF, nor even valid XML.

Comment: The RDF is just a dummy placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an `OntModel` is a subclass of `Model` and `addSubModel` is "by reference" so changing the submodel is relfected in the top level OntModel.